# Let's document that site reviews are off topic

Tags: feature-request, faq-contents, close-reasons

There's a custom close reason for Site Reviews (in the Off-Topic section), but the section of the FAQs titled "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)," does not explicitly say that site reviews are off topic.  We should add this rule to that page.  Adding it will serve two purposes:

1. It will let new users know that site-reviews are off topic.
2. It will give reviewers a page to link to when close-voting.  That way, users who post asking for site reviews can be greeted with a personal explanation of why their question is off-topic rather than running up against an impersonal close reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good idea. However the page you've linked to (the Don't Ask page) is a network-wide one. All Stack Exchange sites have the same content on that page and it isn't editable to be custom for each site.

What we *do* have flexibility over is the [TOUR](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour) page that is displayed to new users. There are some Ask About / Don't Ask About sections in there.

So, i've taken the liberty of removing one of the bullet points in the 'don't ask about' list (the one stating not to ask for primarily opinion-based questions as that's already covered in the text alongside the bullet list) and added in a Site Reviews item in there instead.

Comment: Regarding the page to link when close voting, we could also do a more in-depth answer on Meta. Anything that's more than one line should probably stay out of the Tour. And site reviews are already mentioned on the tour

Comment: @BenBrocka: Are they? Or are they only mentioned in there because I've just added it in?

Comment: Oh, you just added it in, I thought we already had that in there but I guess not.